# How to measure total downloaded bytes over a longer period?

Tags: windows, networking, logging, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software to report internet traffic for home user](https://superuser.com/questions/107879/software-to-report-internet-traffic-for-home-user)

I am interested in measuring the number of total downloaded bytes (TCP/IP), on a per month basis.

Which tool would You recommend?